# .dockerVolume() of WebdriverManager causes (Connection reset) error on Linux-VM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, docker-volume, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

I run my tests in docker by using webdrivermanager. I need to upload some files into the running docker. So, I will be able to use those files in my tests. I used `.dockerVolume()` like:

```
WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().enableVnc().enableRecording().dockerVolumes("/home/GitHub/e2e-test:/home/selenium");
driver = wdm.create();
```

It is working well on my local well. But I need to run the tests on a GCP VM instance: **Debian GNU/Linux 11**

It was working well on the VM without using `.dockerVolume()` like:

```
WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().enableVnc().enableRecording();
driver = wdm.create();
```

So, briefly, It is working on my local **with and without** `.dockerVolume()`. However, it is not working on the VM with `.dockerVolume()`.

I keep getting the error below:

> io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException: **There was an error creating WebDriver object for Chrome**
> at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.instantiateDriver(WebDriverManager.java:1775)
> at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.create(WebDriverManager.java:425)
> at e2e.toolset.WebDriverTool.setDriver(WebDriverTool.java:13)

How can I solve this issue?

Logs in details:

> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------- [INFO]
> T E S T S [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] Running e2e.TestRunner
>
> @regression Scenario: DataScout Login                      #
> src/test/resources/features/DataScout.feature:4 2023-02-16 11:49:29
> [main] DEBUG i.g.b.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache.checkValidity(156) -
> Removing resolution chrome-container-latest=106.0 from cache (expired
> on Thu Oct 20 09:53:59 UTC 2022) 2023-02-16 11:49:29 [main] DEBUG
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerHubService.listTags(60) - Getting browser image
> list from Docker Hub 2023-02-16 11:49:29 [main] TRACE
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerHubService.listTags(73) - Sending request to
> https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/selenoid/vnc/tags?page=1&page_size=1024
> 2023-02-16 11:49:30 [main] TRACE
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerHubService.listTags(73) - Sending request to
> https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/selenoid/vnc/tags?page=2&page_size=1024
> 2023-02-16 11:49:30 [main] TRACE
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerHubService.listTags(73) - Sending request to
> https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/selenoid/vnc/tags?page=3&page_size=1024
> 2023-02-16 11:49:31 [main] DEBUG
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.getImageVersionFromDockerHub(471) - The
> latest version of Chrome in Docker Hub is 110.0 2023-02-16 11:49:31
> [main] TRACE i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.getDockerImage(517) -
> Docker image: selenoid/vnc:chrome_110.0 2023-02-16 11:49:31 [main]
> INFO  i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.pullImageIfNecessary(330) -
> Pulling Docker image selenoid/vnc:chrome_110.0 (this might take some
> time, but only the first time) 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
> i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.pullImageIfNecessary(336) - Docker
> image selenoid/vnc:chrome_110.0 pulled 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main]
> DEBUG
> i.g.b.wdm.cache.ResolutionCache.putValueInResolutionCacheIfEmpty(119)
>
> - Storing resolution chrome-container-latest=110.0 in cache (valid until 12:49:32 16/02/2023 UTC) 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.config.Config.getDockerMemSizeBytes(1142) - The
>   memory size 256m is equivalent to 268435456 bytes) 2023-02-16 11:49:32
>   [main] TRACE
>   i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.config.Config.getDockerMemSizeBytes(1142) - The
>   memory size 128m is equivalent to 134217728 bytes) 2023-02-16 11:49:32
>   [main] TRACE i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startBrowserContainer(638)
> - Using custom volumes: [/home/furkan_yavuz/e2e-tests/src/test/resources/testData:/home/selenium]
>   2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] INFO
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(177) - Starting Docker
>   container selenoid/vnc:chrome_110.0 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(190) - Adding sysadmin
>   capability 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(196) - Using shm size:
>   268435456 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(202) - Using network:
>   bridge 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(207) - Using exposed
>   ports: [4444, 5900] 2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(216) - Using binds:
>   [/home/furkan_yavuz/e2e-tests/src/test/resources/testData:/home/selenium:rw]
>   2023-02-16 11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(222) - Using mounts:
>   [Mount(type=TMPFS, source=null, target=/tmp, readOnly=null,
>   bindOptions=null, volumeOptions=null,
>   tmpfsOptions=TmpfsOptions(sizeBytes=134217728, mode=null))] 2023-02-16
>   11:49:32 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startContainer(228) - Using envs:
>   [TZ=Etc/UTC, LANG=EN, SCREEN_RESOLUTION=1280x1080x24, ENABLE_VNC=true,
>   DRIVER_ARGS=--whitelisted-ips= --allowed-origins=*] 2023-02-16
>   11:49:33 [main] TRACE i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.getBindPort(294)
> - Port list {5900/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@217bf99e,
>   4444/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@6807a356} --
>   Exposed port 4444/tcp = [0.0.0.0:49197, :::49197] 2023-02-16 11:49:33
>   [main] TRACE i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startBrowserContainer(693)
> - Browser remote URL http://localhost:49197/ 2023-02-16 11:49:33 [main] TRACE i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.getBindPort(294) - Port
>   list
>   {5900/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@d675f9f,
>   4444/tcp=[Lcom.github.dockerjava.api.model.Ports$Binding;@58af5076} --
>   Exposed port 5900/tcp = [0.0.0.0:49196, :::49196] 2023-02-16 11:49:33
>   [main] DEBUG i.g.b.wdm.docker.DockerService.startBrowserContainer(700)
> - VNC server URL: vnc://localhost:49196/ 2023-02-16 11:49:33 [main] TRACE i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.createDockerWebDriver(1893)
> - The Selenium Serverl URL is http://localhost:49197/ 2023-02-16 11:49:33 [main] DEBUG
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(77) -
>   Creating WebDriver object for chrome at http://localhost:49197/ with
>   Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args:
>   [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}} 2023-02-16 11:49:34 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SocketException creating WebDriver object (**Connection reset**)
>   2023-02-16 11:49:35 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(86) -
>   Requesting http://localhost:49197/ (the response code is 404) Feb 16,
>   2023 11:49:35 AM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.opentelemetry.OpenTelemetryTracer
>   createTracer INFO: Using OpenTelemetry for tracing 2023-02-16 11:49:36
>   [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SessionNotCreatedException creating WebDriver object (Could not start
>   a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome
>   failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)  Host info: host: 'selenium-tests',
>   ip: '10.156.0.4' Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '5.10.0-18-cloud-amd64', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession
>   {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}],
>   desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome,
>   goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
>   Capabilities {}) 2023-02-16 11:49:37 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(86) -
>   Requesting http://localhost:49197/ (the response code is 404)
>   2023-02-16 11:49:37 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SessionNotCreatedException creating WebDriver object (Could not start
>   a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome
>   failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)  Host info: host: 'selenium-tests',
>   ip: '10.156.0.4' Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '5.10.0-18-cloud-amd64', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession
>   {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}],
>   desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome,
>   goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
>   Capabilities {}) 2023-02-16 11:49:38 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(86) -
>   Requesting http://localhost:49197/ (the response code is 404)
>   2023-02-16 11:49:38 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SessionNotCreatedException creating WebDriver object (Could not start
>   a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome
>   failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)  Host info: host: 'selenium-tests',
>   ip: '10.156.0.4' Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '5.10.0-18-cloud-amd64', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession
>   {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}],
>   desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome,
>   goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
>   Capabilities {}) 2023-02-16 11:49:39 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(86) -
>   Requesting http://localhost:49197/ (the response code is 404)
>   2023-02-16 11:49:39 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SessionNotCreatedException creating WebDriver object (Could not start
>   a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome
>   failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)  Host info: host: 'selenium-tests',
>   ip: '10.156.0.4' Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '5.10.0-18-cloud-amd64', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession
>   {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}],
>   desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome,
>   goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
>   Capabilities {}) 2023-02-16 11:49:40 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(86) -
>   Requesting http://localhost:49197/ (the response code is 404)
>   2023-02-16 11:49:41 [main] TRACE
>   i.g.b.wdm.webdriver.WebDriverCreator.createRemoteWebDriver(92) -
>   SessionNotCreatedException creating WebDriver object (Could not start
>   a new session. **Response code 500**. Message: unknown error: Chrome
>   failed to start: crashed.   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file
>   doesn't exist)   (The process started from chrome location
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
>   assuming that Chrome has crashed.)  Host info: host: 'selenium-tests',
>   ip: '10.156.0.4' Build info: version: '4.6.0', revision: '79f1c02ae20'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '5.10.0-18-cloud-amd64', java.version: '17.0.6' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession
>   {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions:
>   {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}],
>   desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome,
>   goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]

Related Github issue link: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/996

Comment: Hi @Furkan will this [link](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/726) helps?

Comment: Hello @DharaniDharGolladasari, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the reason for this issue. But I have a solution to overcome.

I read the container ID and used command line executions to copy files to the newly created container.

```
    String contaionerID = wdm.getDockerBrowserContainerId().toLowerCase().substring(0, 12); // get chrome container ID
    String commandForCopyTheCSV = "docker cp {file_directory} " + contaionerID + ":/home/selenium";
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandForCopyTheCSV).waitFor(); // copy the file
```